# I'm reading open source code (C++) and can't figure out why they put enum this way

Tags: c++, c, enums

I found enum be defined like this and can't figure it out why they put leading zero there.

```
enum SquareDelta {
  DELTA_SSW = -021,
  DELTA_SS = -020,
  DELTA_SSE = -017,
  DELTA_SWW = -012,
  DELTA_SW = -011,
  DELTA_S = -010,
  DELTA_SE = -07,
  DELTA_SEE = -06,
  DELTA_W = -01,
  DELTA_ZERO = 0,
  DELTA_E = 01,
  DELTA_NWW = 06,
  DELTA_NW = 07,
  DELTA_N = 010,
  DELTA_NE = 011,
  DELTA_NEE = 012,
  DELTA_NNW = 017,
  DELTA_NN = 020,
  DELTA_NNE = 021
};
```

I guess this is not just normal int enum but what is it? could it be in hex like number beginning with "0x" ?

Comment: The basic concept appears to be using three bits (an octal is 3 bits, nothing to do with the number of digits) to keep track of how far north/south, and three bits to keep track of how far east/west. NNE = N + N + E = 010 + 010 + 001.  SWW = S + W + W = -010 + -001 + -001.  I would have guessed that negatives in twos compliment makes the usage more confusing though.

Comment: @Mooing Duck: Yay decrypting skills!

Comment: Guess not, the lowest 3 bits are E/W, but the next 3 bits only vaguely correspond to N/S.

Comment: oh no !!,they didnt put any comment with this in the project .. that's just sad :(

Answer (score 39):

Those numbers are octal constants. (Numbers leading with `0` but not `0x` are considered in base-8).

Thus, -021 == -17, -020 = -16, etc.

Answer (score 21):

Those are Octal literals and hence they start with 0.

*What is more interesting & real Question to me is:

**Why to use Octal Literals as enum values?***

Probably, because each bit of those octal literals is indicative of something. It is difficult to make out what, just by seeing the enum and no context where it is being used, but you need to think about it in that direction, and perhaps it will make more sense for you.

Comment: +1 because there is probably a hidden property behind those numbers

Comment: It's like you said. It's been done this way for bit operation.

Comment: @Oreo23: Glad could help. Can you elaborate a little more about the bit usage in the Q itself, it is interesting, Also it will help some other user who might be stuck at this same/similar doubt.

Comment: Those look like radians to me.

Answer (score 11):

The other "answers" answer your question, but I'm adding this for informative purposes.

```
enum SquareDelta {
               DELTA_NNW= 017,DELTA_NN = 020,DELTA_NNE= 021
DELTA_NWW= 006,DELTA_NW = 007,DELTA_N  = 010,DELTA_NE = 011,DELTA_NEE= 012,
               DELTA_W  =-001,DELTA_ZER= 000,DELTA_E  = 001,
DELTA_SWW=-012,DELTA_SW =-011,DELTA_S  =-010,DELTA_SE =-007,DELTA_SEE=-006,
               DELTA_SSW=-021,DELTA_SS =-020,DELTA_SSE=-017,  
 };
```

Again, in binary (twos compliment):

```
enum SquareDelta {
                 DELTA_NNW=001111,DELTA_NN =010000,DELTA_NNE=010001
DELTA_NWW=000110,DELTA_NW =000111,DELTA_N  =001000,DELTA_NE =001001,DELTA_NEE=001010,
                 DELTA_W  =111111,DELTA_ZER=000000,DELTA_E  =000001,
DELTA_SWW=110110,DELTA_SW =110111,DELTA_S  =111000,DELTA_SE =111001,DELTA_SEE=111010,
                 DELTA_SSW=101111,DELTA_SS =110000,DELTA_SSE=110001,  
 };
```

So the E/W Coordinate is `SquareDelta&7`, and the N/S Coordinate is `SquareDelta&070+SquareDelta&4`.

Upon further review, it seems that they intended for the least significant octal digit to be on a scale from -2 to 2 to signify the W/E-ness, and the next octal digit to scale from -2 to 2 to signify the N/S-ness.  If you add `DELTA_W+DELTA_W+DELTA_N` and truncate to two octal digits, you get 006, the value of `DELTA_NWW`.  Since the least significant octal affects the upper, the deltas are limited to plus or minus two.

Answer (score 4):

Those are 8-based (**Edit:** the word is octal :) ) numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Leading zero makes them base 8 numbers. e.g. 021 = 17

Comment: Not necessary. Your answer is incomplete. `0x20` is not octal number, yet it starts with `0`.

Answer (score 1):

a) Literal constants, beginning with 0 are octal (digits from 0 to 7)
 b) The actual numbers allow some arithmetics, like N=10 + 2*(E=1) = 12 (NEE).

But since NE > N && NW > N, it does not reflect a direction in the circle, so it is, maybe, of limited help, like the word 'SquareDelta' for me. Maybe, it makes more sense in context.